# Sync dates without calendar web part to Outlook/Google/Desktop Calendars

Tags: javascript, outlook, sharepoint-2010

This is my first time attempting to implement functionality for a calendar. What i'm attempting to do is takes dates from a list (along with other info like the title of events, description of events, host of event, etc.) and sync it with the user's default calendar OR a preferred calendar, like google/outlook calendars. I'm attempting to achieve this with javascript.

What I currently envision is I get the data using [SP Services](https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/), which I already do. I'm using this to build an event's "list view" using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), which I also already have working.

Now, I would like to add a button on each event that says "Add to Calendar" and when clicked, it either adds the event to the default calendar (useful for desktop calendars?) or allows the user to choose a calendar to add to (between google/outlook,etc.). On top of that, I would like to have a button that chooses a batch of events to add to their calendar.

I know this is something far beyond what I currently know or JavaScript but would be grateful for any direction. I've already started by reading through Google Calendar API but it's quite a bit to take in still. Also, another note, The user's on the SharePoint are employees with a default outlook email. I'm assuming that would be the easiest way to add events but i'm not sure how to A) Get access to their calendar just by their signed in account and B) how to authorize additions to the calendar.

If it's all beneficial, this is my current code using SP Services and Datatables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var method = "GetListItems";
        var webURL = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();
        var list = "Events List";
        var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" + "<FieldRef Name='Name' />" + "</ViewFields>";
        var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'  Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>";
        var pre = [];
        var dataSet = [];
        var i = 0;
        $().SPServices({
            operation: method,
            async: false,
            webURL: webURL,
            listName: list,
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
            CAMLQuery: query,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

                    var pre = [];
                    var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                    var host = $(this).attr("ows_EventHost");
                    var bdate = $(this).attr("ows_StartDate");
                    bdate = dateFromSharepoint(bdate);
                    var edate = $(this).attr("ows_EndDate");
                    if (edate === null | edate === '') {
                        edate = bdate
                    } else {
                        edate = dateFromSharepoint(edate);
                    }

                    var bdatein = moment(bdate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');
                    var edatein = moment(edate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');
                    var category = $(this).attr("ows_Category");
                    var body = $(this).attr("ows_Body");
                    var loc = $(this).attr("ows_Location");
                    var auth = $(this).attr("ows_Author");
                    var created = $(this).attr("ows_Created");
                    var modified = $(this).attr("ows_Modified").split(" ")[0];
                    var ID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                    var sumcomms = Number($(this).attr("ows_sumcomms"));
                    var dateSearchable = moment(bdate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')


                    body = $(body).text();
                    auth = auth.substring(auth.indexOf("#") + 1);
                    host = host.substring(host.indexOf("#") + 1);
                    category = category.substring(category.indexOf("#") + 1);

                    if (category.replace(/\s/g, '') === 'WorkinProgress') {
                        category = 'WIP'
                    }
                    if (title == null) {
                        title = ''
                    }
                    if (loc == null) {
                        loc = "Unspecified"
                    }

                    pre.push(category, title, host, bdatein, loc, sumcomms, auth, edatein, ID, body, created, modified, bdate, edate, dateSearchable, '');
                    dataSet[i] = pre;

                    i++;
                });
            }
        });

        maketables(dataSet, 'FTable');
    });

 function maketables(dataset, table) {
        table = $('#' + table).DataTable({
            data: dataset,
            sDom: '<"top"lf>rt<"bottom"p>',
            iDisplayLength: 50,
            bsearching: false,
            bInfo: false,
            bPaginate: true,
            bProcessing: true,
            order: [
                [12, 'desc']
            ],
            createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
                switch (data[0]) {

                    case 'WIP':
                        $(row).find('td:first').addClass('btn btn-success btn-outline').css('min-width','100px').append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
                        break;

                    case 'Chalk Talk':
                        $(row).find('td:first').addClass('btn btn-warning btn-outline').css('min-width','100px').append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
                        break;

                    case 'Social':
                        $(row).find('td:first').addClass('btn btn-primary btn-outline ').css('min-width','100px').append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
                        break;

                    default:
                        $(row).find('td:first').addClass('btn btn-danger btn-outline ').css('min-width','100px').append(' <span class="caret"></span>');
                        break;
                }


            },

            columns: [{
                    title: "Category",
                    name: "category",
                    className: "details-control",
                    orderable: true,
                    DefaultContent: 'Other'
                },
                {
                    title: "Title",
                    name: "title",
                    orderable: false,
                    defaultContent: ''
                },
                {
                    title: "Host",
                    name: "host"

                },
                {
                    title: "Begins",
                    name: "bdatein"
                },

                {
                    title: "Location",
                    name: "loc",
                    visible: false,
                    defaultContent: 'Not Specified'
                },

                {
                    title: "Comments",
                    name: "totalcomms",
                    orderable: false,
                    visible: false,
                    defaultContent: ''
                },
                {
                    title: "Posted By",
                    name: "author",
                    orderable: false,
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    title: "Ends",
                    name: "edatein",
                    visible: false,
                    defaultContent: ''
                },
                {
                    title: "ID",
                    name: "id",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    title: "Details (full)",
                    name: "body",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    visible: false,
                    defaultContent: ''
                },
                {
                    title: "Created Date",
                    name: "created",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    title: "Last Modified",
                    name: "modified",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    title: "Begins (Full)",
                    name: "bdate",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    visible: false
                },
                {
                    title: "Ends (Full)",
                    name: "edate",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    visible: false,
                    defaultContent: ''
                },
                {
                    title: "Searchable Date",
                    name: "sDate",
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: true,
                    visible: false,
                    defaultContent: ''
                },
                {
                    title: "Edit",
                    DefaultContent: ''
                }
            ],

            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 15,
                render: function(data, type, row) {

                    if (userName !== null && userName === row[2]) {
                        return '<a href="javascript:editModal(' + row[8] + ')">Edit</a>';
                    } else if (userName !== null && userName === row[6]) {
                        return '<a href="javascript:editModal(' + row[8] + ')">Edit</a>';
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            }],
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
                $(oSettings.nTHead).hide();
            }
        });



        $('#FTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            } else {
                // Open this row
                row.child(dateParts(row.data())).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        });

        $('#filter-WIP').on('click', function() {
                $(this).siblings('.btn').removeClass(function(index, className) {
                    return (className.match(/(^|\s)full-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                });
                $(this).addClass('full-wip');
                table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
                table.columns(0).search('WIP').draw();
            }

        );
        $('#filter-Other').on('click', function() {
                $(this).siblings('.btn').removeClass(function(index, className) {
                    return (className.match(/(^|\s)full-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                });
                $(this).addClass('full-oth');
                table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
                table.columns(0).search('Other').draw();
            }

        );
        $('#filter-Social').on('click', function() {
                $(this).siblings('.btn').removeClass(function(index, className) {
                    return (className.match(/(^|\s)full-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                });
                $(this).addClass('full-soc');
                table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
                table.columns(0).search('Social').draw();
            }

        );
        $('#filter-CT').on('click', function() {
                $(this).siblings('.btn').removeClass(function(index, className) {
                    return (className.match(/(^|\s)full-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                });

                $(this).addClass('full-ct');
                table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
                table.columns(0).search('Chalk Talk').draw();
            }

        );
        $('#filter-All').on('click', function() {
                $(this).siblings('.btn').removeClass(function(index, className) {
                    return (className.match(/(^|\s)full-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                });
                $(this).addClass('full-all');
                table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
                table.columns(0).search('').draw();
            }

        );


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just using separate functions for OAuth to google/outlook calendars and never implemented a solution for a group of events